# strict mode return this w/o violation

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-5, strict-mode

I want to have my cake and eat it too: I want to have a method that returns `this` for chaining when it is bound to an object but returns `undefined` when it is called with a null|undefined scope. This seems to work fine but if you put it into [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) then you get a Strict Violation errors. I don't need to use strict mode, but it seems like this should be possible and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/hYZNr/6/) (open the console). Is this okay and/or how else could you accomplish this effect?

```
var o = {}; // or some pre-existing module
o.meth = (function (undefined) {

    // contrived example where you'd want to be able to locally 
    // access `meth` even if the outer `o.meth` was overwritten

    'use strict';

    var hash = Object.create(null); // "object" with no properties

    // global ref - or `null` where strict mode works
    var cantTouchThis = (function () {
        return this; 
    }).call(null);

    function meth (k, v) {
        var n;
        if (typeof k == 'object') { // set multi
            for (n in k) {
                meth(n, k[n]);
            }
        } else {
             if (v === undefined) { return hash[k]; } // get
             hash[k] = v; // set
        }
        if (this == cantTouchThis) { return; }
        return this;
    }

    return meth;

}());
```

And if you look in the console:

```
var localM = o.meth; // now scopeless
console.log(  o.meth('key', 'val')  ); // should return `o`
console.log(  localM('key', 'val')  ); // should return `undefined`
```

Comment: Some people say that undefined shouldn't be compared this way (== or ===) as it can be redefined somewhere in Your or third parties code. Which is of course a bad habit to do so.

Comment: @PiotrSalaciak Yea I was assuming a clean environment for the sake of the question. I just added `undefined` tho as the first param for ya ( which will be `=== undefined` b/c it's invoked with zero params ;) Another safe way to do it is compare `=== void 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will almost do what you want.

`dontTouchThis` will be `null` in environment that supports "use strict" directive, and will reference global object in those that don't support it.

First of all, you can replace that `.call(null)` chunk with just `(function(){return this})()`; it will have more or less the same effect.

Second, don't forget that there are 4 ways function can be called, when it comes to `this` value: as a method, as a standalone (baseless) function, via call/apply, and with `new` operator. This means that:

- `new (o.meth)` will return `o`
- `o.meth.call(o2, ...)` will return `o2`
- `o.meth.call(null, ...)` will return `undefined`

Finally, if someone aliases `meth` to a global variable, then in strict-mode-supporting environment `meth()` will return global object, not `undefined` since `cantTouchThis` (being `null`) won't be equal to `this` (which will reference global object).

```
// in global scope

var meth = o.meth;
meth(...); // `this` references global object, will return global object

(function() {

  // in local scope
  var meth = o.meth;

  meth(...); // `this` is `undefined`, will return `undefined`

})();
```

Comment: Thanks / yea that helps. I guess in strict mode `root = this || window` is also an option inside a closure, if you know it's being called in the global scope. Or `root = (function(){return this}) || window`. Or save separate refs to the root `this` and to the `window` to be safe. You can see what I was working on @ https://github.com/ryanve/hook

Answer (score 0):

To be redundantly safe, I ended up using a local function for "grounding" scope resolution:

```
var gnd = (function () {
    var globe = this || window;
    return function (o) {
        // for grounding (securing) scope
        return o == null || o === globe ? 0 : o;
    };
}());
```

See usage [in the source here](https://github.com/ryanve/dj/blob/master/dj.js#files).